# Do I need to list a school I attended as a non-degree seeking student on CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I am currently applying for some graduate programs and got a question regarding my CV. I took one course at a different institution than the university I am graduating from. I attended the college as a non-degree seeking student and did not transfer the credits I earned at the college to my university. I am pretty sure that I need to send a transcript from the college, but I have no idea whether and how I list the college on my CV. I appreciate any helpful info in advance!

Comment: Requirements vary. Is this for the US?

Comment: Yes, I only apply to the universities in the States

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly right about the need to send a transcript; nearly every U.S. college and university requires transcripts from *all* institutions the applicant has attended.

That said, an admissions reviewer with transcript in hand will wonder why it's not on the CV.  It makes sense to list it, noting that you were not seeking a degree.  You need not go into detail.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thank you!